# pypyodbc - Reusing a Database Connection

Tags: python, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I have two questions:

QUESTION-1:

Suppose I have two .py File-1 and File-2

File-1 contains the following statements:

```
try:
        cononnection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                                            'SERVER=........'
                                            'DATABASE=......'
                                            'UID=......;PWD=......')
except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the SQL SERVER Database")
```

In File-2, if I use the connection defined in File-1 in the following way:

```
import AnotherPythonFile as File1

def query():     
        conxn1 = File1.cononnection 
        conxn2 = File1.cononnection
        ...
        ...
```

Will conxn1 and conxn2 use the same connection opened in File-1 or they will open two more new connections?

QUESTION-2:

If a 'pypyodbc.DatabaseError' occurs while executing the following statements, then will the connection close automatically (due to the error)?

```
    cursr = connection.cursor()
    cursr.execute(queryStr)
```

Comment: By your syntax, It means only one connection is created.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to wrap the imported module in a defined function and have function return the connection object:

```
# FILE 1
import pypyodbc

def dbconn():
    try:
        cononnection = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                                            'SERVER=........'
                                            'DATABASE=......'
                                            'UID=......;PWD=......')
        return connection 
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the SQL SERVER Database")
```

Then

```
import AnotherPythonFile as File1   

def query():     
     # EACH WILL USE DIFFERENT INSTANCES OF SAME CONNECTION OBJECT
     conxn1 = File1.dbconn()
     conxn2 = File1.dbconn()
```

As for second question, **no**, neither cursor nor database connection is closed automatically when a SQL query execution fails. In fact, you can test this assertion. Purposely, force an error:

```
cursr.execute("SLEECT * FROM Table;")
```

Then, see that you can still call `cursr.close()` and `connection.close()` in Python's console after raised traceback error.

Comment: No, you are wrong. 

conxn1 and conxn2 will have two different contentions as a new connection will be created every time the function is called.

However, after some fiddling around the issue, I am almost certain that conxn1 and conxn2 will share the same contention in the context shown in my original post. But I need corroboration.

Comment: I re-phrased my code comment. Both will share same connection object but in different instances. As for your original post you will need to use `from AnotherPythonFile import connection` but even then you open a different instance with each call to `connection`. RDMS's (I know MySQL does) tracks number of users no doubt based on timestamped instances for record-level locking and other needs. I cannot see how more than one user, including same client/script can share an open connection.